Google App Engine python requests error when routed through proxies
I am seeing some strange behavior in my python script that sends a post request to an api through an https proxy while running on Google App Engine.
main.py
import random
import requests
lines = open(r'proxies.txt').read().splitlines()

# finds a random proxy to use
while True:
    line =random.choice(lines)
    if line.split(':')[2] != "United States":
        continue
    proxy = line.split(':')[0] + ':' + line.split(':')[1]
    website_url = 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json'
    proxy_dict = {
        'https': f'https://{proxy}'
    }
    try:
        response = requests.get(website_url, proxies=proxy_dict, timeout=2, verify=False)
        print(f'\x1b[38;5;47mProxy {proxy} is working for HTTPS.')
        print("current IP: " , response.text , "\n\x1b[1;0m")
        break
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f'\x1b[38;5;3mError occurred while testing proxy {proxy}: {str(e)}\x1b[1;0m')

url = "url of api"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "prd-usta-kube-tournaments.clubspark.pro",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"123\", \"Not:A-Brand\";v=\"8\"",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.6312.88 Safari/537.36",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "Origin": "https://playtennis.usta.com",
    "Referer": "https://playtennis.usta.com/",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Priority": "u=1, i"
}

payload = {
   #payload
}
cookies = {}

r = requests.get(url, json=payload, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, verify=False, proxies=proxy_dict)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'  # Ensure correct encoding

print(r.text)

proxies.txt:
https proxy ip

when the code is run locally, it is perfectly fine, however, when I run the code on Google App Engine, it prints out random characters like this
��������tu�S7���.��JU�,ӳ"#<,��!!A�L��:����#�;��r�6��)�Vj���<hh(����O�RAA�����3Q��0>K.����0�

I originally thought that proxy connections were not allowed on GAE until I realized that the call to check if the proxy was working "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json" was responding with perfectly fine data. I also tested the code with other sites such as https://example.com and it responded with normal data to GAE
I Know the api i am trying to access does have cloudflare protection and is graphql

Your question is unclear. The code won't run on App Engine. Is the code a repro of the code that you're deploying to App Engine? The response appears to be binary-encoded data possibly a result of "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"

i have deployed my actual code to app engine but the code sample I provided was used to test in the App Engine Bash Console. I created a python file in the console and ran it giving me the output.
As for "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br", what should I do to get it into normal text, it should look like this
{"data":{"publishedTournament":{"__typename":"Tournament","cancelledAt":null,"commsSettings":{"__typename":"CommsSettings",
I got the headers from copying the request being sent in devtools

You can try changing the system encoding to UTF-8.

the problem was with the accept-encoding accepting br. I removed br and it worked perfectly ty :)
for some reason when run on GAE it used br encoding but locally it did not.
related: Python requests response encoded in utf-8 but cannot be decoded
